# how to insert a footer only on first page and another only on last page

Tags: ms-word, word-2013

I currently am building a word document which will need 2 different footers.  The first will display only on the 1st page and the 2nd only on the last page.  The pages in between should have no footer or header.  I'm using MS Word 2013.

I have the 1st footer working, it shows up only on the 1st page.  I added it in and selected the "Different First Page" property in MS Word's ribbon and it was fine.  But I'm not sure how to get the 2nd one to show up only on the last page as right now its shows on all pages.  When I select the 2nd one in the footer I see the "Different First Page" and "Different Odd & Even Pages" gets greyed out.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Click the footer at the last page, then try footer format, uncheck 'start from first page' or check 'start at current page'. I can't remember clearly.

Comment: I don't see those, I have "Different First Page" checked, this way it does not show on the first page.  the other options I see in the ribbon for Editing the footer are "Different Odd & Even Pages" which I have unchecked and "Show Document Text" which I have checked.  I don't see anything about only this page.